# How to know the size of the string in bytes?

Tags: c#, .net, string, size, byte

I'm wondering if I can know how long in bytes for a `string` in C#, anyone know?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/net-string-to-byte-array-c-sharp).

Comment: Are you asking how much memory a `string` object occupies, or how many bytes the representation of a string will occupy when written to a file or sent over a network (i.e. encoded), because those are two completely different questions. majidgeek almost answered the former while diya answered the latter (at least for two common encodings).

Comment: possible duplicate of [how much bytes will take?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967411/how-much-bytes-will-take)

Comment: @AllonGuralnek:Good point. do you know why diya below didn't suggest to use System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount instead? Why ASCIIEncoding part?

Comment: @Giorgi: Since `Unicode` is a static property of `System.Text.Encoding`, which is the base class of `ASCIIEncoding`, both statements are actually the same. You can access a static member from  subclasses as well (but it's not considered idiomatic).

Answer (score 183, accepted):

You can use encoding like ASCII to get a character per byte by using the `System.Text.Encoding` class.

or try this

```
  System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(string);
  System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(string);
```

Comment: Stupid question, but how will we know whether to use the Unicode or ASCII class if the data in the string came from a 3rd party file?

Comment: @MatthewLock You should use UTF16 (or majidgeek's `Length * sizeof(Char)`, which should give the same result since each `Char` is UTF16/2-bytes) if you want the same number of bytes as the internal representation of a string. If you actually want the exact amount of memory the entire object takes, rather than just the number of bytes in its internal character array, then you might consider a [more general method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128315/find-size-of-object-instance-in-bytes-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 122):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx):

> A `String` object is a sequential collection of `System.Char` objects that represent a string.

So you can use this:

```
var howManyBytes = yourString.Length * sizeof(Char);
```

Comment: as far as i can understand basics of data structure it's the most 'pined' choise to compare to

Comment: Don't forget to take into account the size of the length member. int howManyBytes = yourString.Length * sizeof(Char) + sizeof(int);

Comment: What if my String length is larger than Int?

Comment: This should be correct answer. Also .Length is what the amount of bytes the server will receive if you send that same string. This is what I was needing.

Comment: This answer is misleading! It will only correctly calculate the amount of bytes taken by the string in RAM by the application, NOT the amount of bytes a file with that string would have, NOR the length of HTTP content with that string, although it might sometimes give the right answer by coincidence. The real answer is that actual number of bytes depends on chosen encoding. This answer's calculation implies UTF-16, .NET's choice for storing strings in RAM, but hardly used anywhere else, so it will most likely give wrong answers, at least it some cases.

Answer (score 29):

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(yourString);
```

Or

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(yourString);
```

Answer (score 12):

How many bytes a `string` will take depends on the encoding you choose (or is automatically chosen in the background without your knowledge). This sample code shows the difference:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

static void Main()
{
    Encoding testedEncodings = new[]
    {
        Encoding.ASCII,   // Note that '' cannot be encoded in ASCII, data loss will occur
        Encoding.UTF8,    // This should always be your choice nowadays
        Encoding.Unicode, // This is UTF-16. It is used by .NET to store your strings in RAM when the application is running, but this isn't useful information unless you're trying to manipulate bytes in RAM
        Encoding.UTF32
    };

    string text = "a";

    Console.WriteLine($"Tested string: {text}");
    Console.WriteLine($"String length: {text.Length}");
    Console.WriteLine();

    PrintTableHeader("Encoding", "Bytes", "Decoded string");

    foreach (var encoding in testedEncodings)
    {
        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(text);
        string decodedString = encoding.GetString(bytes);

        PrintTableRow(
            encoding.EncodingName,
            $"{bytes.Length} ({string.Join(' ', bytes)})",
            decodedString);
    }
}

static void PrintTableHeader(params string[] values)
{
    PrintTableRow(values);
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 60));
}

static void PrintTableRow(params string[] values)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-16} | {1,-24} | {2}", values);
}
```

Output:

```
Tested string: a
String length: 3

Encoding         | Bytes                    | Decoded string
------------------------------------------------------------
US-ASCII         | 3 (97 63 63)             | a??
Unicode (UTF-8)  | 5 (97 240 159 161 170)   | a
Unicode          | 6 (97 0 62 216 106 220)  | a
Unicode (UTF-32) | 8 (97 0 0 0 106 248 1 0) | a
```