# Get the size of a string

Tags: c#

I wish to know how to calculate the size of string data type.
says what is the size of s under the following scenario?

```
string s="";
string s="1";
string s="12";
```

If possible, can point to a website mentioned this?

Comment: Define "size"? Number of characters? Number of unicode points? (this is not necessarily the same) Number of bytes under a yet-to-be-specified encoding? Number of pixels? Number of millimetres? Number of bytes comprising the `string` instance?

Comment: If you're asking about the number of characters, then I think you should get yourself a c# book and read it before posting anything on the internet, because those are the absolute basics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer to this link: [How to know the size of the string in bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707755/how-to-know-the-size-of-the-string-in-bytes)

```
System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(s);
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(s);
```

or from msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx

Comment: Right. Just want to point out, that he will have to use the encoding according to the string he has :)

Comment: @BoasEnkler: What do you mean by that? A string in .NET doesn't *have* any idea of an encoding; or rather, the "native" representation is always UTF-16. It's not like there's such a thing as a "UTF-8 string".

Comment: Yes your right. I mixed up the fact that in files he could have diffenrent encodnings, but reading them in .net. would again end in UTF-16. My mistake :)

Answer (score 5):

It is not clear from your question what you meant.

If by size you mean **how many characters**, then `Length` is the property you are looking for

```
"".Length   // 0
"1".Length  // 1
"12".Length // 2
```

If by size you mean **how many bytes** then this is dependant on encoding and you can use the answer Snake Eyes has given

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount("")   // 0
Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount("")      // 0

Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount("1")  // 2
Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount("1")     // 1

Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount("12") // 4
Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount("12")    // 2
```

If by size you mean **value of the number** then you will need to parse the text

```
Int32.Parse("")   // FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format
Int32.Parse("1")  // 1
Int32.Parse("12") // 12
```

Comment: OP asks for size of string, not length, is a difference.

Comment: @SnakeEyes The OP may not have used the correct word. Your answer deals with one possibility, mine another. And I did clarify this point in the first part of my answer "If by size you mean how many characters".

Comment: I think for `size` means `how many kilobytes` use, for `length` how many characters contain.

Comment: And he mentioned: `size of string data type`, not a string as value.

Comment: Until the OP clarifies his/her answer, all we can do is guess their intentions!

Comment: I voted up because you provided complete answer

Answer (score 0):

please use the code below

```
long size=sizeof(char) *s.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

LMGTFY

Anything and everything string
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx

String Length
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx

String number of bytes (and string to byte array is covered in examples)
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3739zdy(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3739zdy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)