# Get the size, in bytes, of how much a string will occupy when written to a file?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, unicode, character-encoding

I've been reading answers that explains how to get the size of a string, size in memory or size in file:

- [How to know the size of the string in bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707755/how-to-know-the-size-of-the-string-in-bytes)
- [Find size of object instance in bytes in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128315/find-size-of-object-instance-in-bytes-in-c-sharp)
- [How to know the byte size of a string? - MSDN social](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/053aa028-774c-4a81-9586-16cb0e469177/how-to-know-the-byte-size-of-a-string)

My intention is to detemine the amount of bytes that a string will occupy, in specified encoding, when written to file.

However, my function does not return the expected result when I check the size of a string for `Encoding.UTF8`, `Encoding.Unicode` (UTF-16) or `Encoding.UTF32`.

This is what I'm doing:

```
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' Gets the size, in bytes, of how much a string will occupy when written to a file.
''' </summary>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------
<DebuggerStepThrough>
<Extension>
Public Function SizeInFile(ByVal sender As String,
                           Optional ByVal encoding As Encoding = Nothing) As Integer

    If (encoding Is Nothing) Then
        encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default
    End If

    Return encoding.GetByteCount(sender)

End Function
```

This is how I'm testing it, in the code below, the function says the string size is 2 bytes, but when written to a file the filesize is 4 bytes:

```
Dim str As String = "Ñ"
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Size of String : {0}", str.SizeInFile(Encoding.Unicode)))

File.WriteAllText(".\Test.txt", str, Encoding.Unicode)
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Size of txtfile: {0}", New FileInfo(".\Test.txt").Length))
```

What am I missing to perform an efficient evaluation of the string size?.

In C# or VB.NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A file may begin with a byte order mark (called BOM) that helps the reader to detect what encoding was used.

The BOM for UTF8 is 3 bytes EF,BB,BF

For UTF16 (Encoding.Unicode) 2 bytes FEFF (encoded as either big endian or little endian depending on the encoding)

For UTF32 4 bytes 0000FEFF

Comment: Ouch! I totally missed the BOM. Now I see that I did a very stupid question because I really knew what is the BOM but just I didn't taken it into account. Thanks a lot!