# How to check memory size of HtmlDocument created with HtmlAgilityPack, or any other document?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack, memory-size

In my application I am trying to calculate how much `HtmlAgilityPack` creates data memory flow when loading documents.

For example, if I am loading `HtmlDocument` to my memory, how to verify what is size of single document, when executing code below? As I belive, it will match the size of memory flow created for http request -> result, am I right?

```
HtmlDocument doc = await web.LoadFromWebAsync("https://www.somefancywebsite.com/");
```

What is memory size of the `doc` object?

I did not managed to find similar topic on SO, and Im sorry if it is something obvious. I am suspecting, that I supposed to convert the document to some other format, where easily I could verify its memory size? Should this do the job correctly? Or should I take it ToArray? Or similar approach?

```
int memorySize = doc.ToString().Legth //size in bytes??
```

**EDIT:** in [this article](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Strings) I found, that each string takes `20+(n/2)*4` bytes, where `n` is quantity of characters. Maybe using this formula?

**EDIT:** as it is managed object, I was trying out solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8165810/12603542) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3173599/12603542). Unfortunatelly I am getting exception on `doc` object:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type
>   'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument' in Assembly 'HtmlAgilityPack (...)

**EDIT:** basing on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16354472/12603542) solution, I am trying to convert `doc.ToString()`, as it is basically text document, what gives me sort of result, but  I am not completely satisfied with this. I am just wondering how much I can rely on this solution and whether there are any alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Using the class `TestSize<T>` from this [github](https://github.com/CyberSaving/MemoryUsage/blob/master/Main/Program.cs) and calling its sizing method was viewed as a safe method according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41651652/7813290). This method seems to work for most types. However, when attempting to find the bytes of a string, it seemed to be better for me to use

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(myString);
```

One thing to note is that the architecture (32-bit/64-bit) as well as version of C# may use different memory sizes.